# Iterating through two lists with 'if... or' statement

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, try-except

I have 3 lists.

```
values_to_add = []
values_to_remove = []
values_to_keep = []
```

Only one of the lists is populated at a time. If one of two of the lists is populated, I would like to perform this action:

```
if values_to_remove or values_to_keep:
    if values_to_remove:
        for value in values_to_remove:
            try:
                value_object.related_value.get(value=value)
            except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
                raise UnableToUpdate("These values are not related!")
    elif values_to_keep:
        for value in values_to_keep:
            try:
                value_object.related_value.get(value=value)
            except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
                raise UnableToUpdate("These values are not related!")
```

However this code seems clunky and I am sure there is a more concise way to write this as it is literally repeating code. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the goal of your code?

Answer (score 2):

```
if values_to_remove or values_to_keep:
    for value in (values_to_remove if len(values_to_remove) else values_to_keep):
        try:
            value_object.related_value.get(value=value)
        except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise UnableToUpdate("These values are not related!")
```

Comment: btw, the first line is redundant.

Comment: if there is a case when both: values_to_remove and values_to_keep are not empty - we need this line. in another case - sure, it is not necessary to use it. let ts choose the best for him.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the upper if statement away and it probably wouldn't have any consequences for the functionality of the code. This would make it cleaner and a bit faster.

```
if values_to_remove:
    for value in values_to_remove:
        try:
            value_object.related_value.get(value=value)
        except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise UnableToUpdate("These values are not related!")
elif values_to_keep:
    for value in values_to_keep:
        try:
            value_object.related_value.get(value=value)
        except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise UnableToUpdate("These values are not related!")
```

You could also use a matrix (2D array) to iterate trough all your arrays, like this:

```
values = [
    [], #values_to_keep
    [] #values_to_remove
]

for array in values:
    if array:
        for value in values_to_remove:
            try:
                value_object.related_value.get(value=value)
            except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
                raise UnableToUpdate("These values are not related!")
        break
```

Though I would only recommend doing this with a lot more arrays, since otherwise it makes your code more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that only one list is populated then you can just run the two loops in sequence:

```
for value in values_to_remove:
    # body elided 

for value in values_to_keep:
    # body elided
```

or since the bodies are the same:

```
def body(value):
    # body elided
for value in values_to_remove + values_to_keep:
    body(value)
```